# Remove whitespaces or line break within a String

Tags: php

I've been googling around and played between ltrim(), rtrim() , trim() and preg_replace() but still I cant find the exact solution that I been looking for.

Here's my sample String/Content from view source:

```
<br>Text1
<br>Text2
<br>            
<br>            
<br>
<br>Text3
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>Text4
```

//OUTPUT SHOULD BE

```
  <br>Text1
  <br>Text2
  <br>Text3 
  <br>Text4
```

I tried this but seems not working:

```
   preg_replace('#<br />(\s*<br />)+#', '<br />', $string);
```

UPDATE (2014-01-24):
  How about this one from viewSource also (im not sure if its a whitespaces or newline) instead of `<br>` ?

```
      Text1
      Text2



      Text3




      Text4
```

Output Should be:

```
      Text1
      Text2

      Text3

      Text4
```

Comment: There's no `<br />` in your input string. Just `<br>`.

Comment: http://3v4l.org/FdR8C

Answer (score 0):

Make use of this pattern `~(<br>\w*[^\s*])~`

```
preg_replace('#(<br>\w*[^\s*])#', '<br />', $string);
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xM5jI6)

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will work for removing 
 tag from your string

```
$str = preg_replace("/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string   = trim(strip_tags($string));
$patterns = array("/\s+/", "/\s([?.!])/");
$replacer = array(" ","$1");
$searchTerm = preg_replace($patterns, $replacer, $string);
```